# How do I get Thread.Priority to work on Linux (.NET Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, linux, multithreading, .net-core

I'm having trouble getting Thread.Prority to do anything in a Linux build. It looks like the code to convert Thread.Priority to posix is [there in the code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/59160) (thanks huoyaoyuan) but I can't get this to work for me.
To demonstrate this, I've used a modified version of the code in the [Thread.Priority doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.priority?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Threading.Thread.Priority)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1) which runs more threads so it works sensibly with multiple cores.

This is the output I get running on Windows (win-x64):

> thread_5    with AboveNormal priority has a count =   563,441,005
> thread_15   with      Normal priority has a count =   251,310,557
> thread_3    with      Normal priority has a count =   239,580,270
> thread_0    with      Normal priority has a count =   236,077,285
> thread_2    with AboveNormal priority has a count =   537,902,014
> thread_4    with BelowNormal priority has a count =     5,903,969
> thread_7    with BelowNormal priority has a count =     5,958,548
> thread_8    with AboveNormal priority has a count =   555,518,195
> thread_11   with AboveNormal priority has a count =   549,665,909
> thread_12   with      Normal priority has a count =   258,493,564
> thread_14   with AboveNormal priority has a count =   550,025,919
> thread_9    with      Normal priority has a count =   135,923,866
> thread_6    with      Normal priority has a count =   138,882,526
> thread_13   with BelowNormal priority has a count =     4,273,232
> thread_1    with BelowNormal priority has a count =     4,608,543
> thread_10   with BelowNormal priority has a count =     5,908,285

This is what I get on Ubuntu (linux-x64):

> thread_4    with BelowNormal priority has a count =   465,192,119
> thread_11   with AboveNormal priority has a count =   558,351,324
> thread_9    with      Normal priority has a count =   459,901,696
> thread_10   with BelowNormal priority has a count =   484,271,783
> thread_7    with BelowNormal priority has a count =   519,165,910
> thread_14   with AboveNormal priority has a count =   487,836,279
> thread_12   with      Normal priority has a count =   465,635,561
> thread_3    with      Normal priority has a count =   450,569,622
> thread_5    with AboveNormal priority has a count =   503,227,636
> thread_6    with      Normal priority has a count =   499,300,694
> thread_8    with AboveNormal priority has a count =   515,728,537
> thread_1    with BelowNormal priority has a count =   547,473,038
> thread_15   with      Normal priority has a count =   462,427,461
> thread_13   with BelowNormal priority has a count =   526,524,771
> thread_2    with AboveNormal priority has a count =   493,184,092
> thread_0    with      Normal priority has a count =   465,902,186

So it looks like all the threads are running at the same priority on Linux.

I've used setcap to give the app the required permissions:
*sudo setcap 'cap_sys_nice=eip' ./ThreadPriorityTest*
but that doesn't make any difference.

What am I missing?

Here's my modified sample code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using Timers = System.Timers;

namespace ThreadPriorityTest
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            PriorityTest priorityTest = new PriorityTest();

            int threadCount = 16;

            List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
            for(int i=0; i<threadCount; i++)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(priorityTest.ThreadMethod);
                thread.Name = $"thread_{i}";
                switch(i%3)
                {
                    case 0:
                        thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
                        break;
                }
                threads.Add(thread);
            }

            Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            Console.WriteLine($"Starting {threadCount} threads...");
            foreach(Thread thread in threads)
            {
                thread.Start();
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Done starting {threadCount} threads.");
            priorityTest.StartEvent.Set();

            // Allow counting for 10 seconds.
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            priorityTest.LoopSwitch = false;
        }
    }

    class PriorityTest
    {
        static volatile bool loopSwitch;
        static ManualResetEvent startEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        [ThreadStatic] static long threadCount = 0;

        public PriorityTest()
        {
            loopSwitch = true;
        }

        public bool LoopSwitch
        {
            set { loopSwitch = value; }
        }

        public ManualResetEvent StartEvent
        {
            get { return startEvent; }
        }

        public void ThreadMethod()
        {
            startEvent.WaitOne();
            while (loopSwitch)
            {
                threadCount++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-11} with {1,11} priority " +
                "has a count = {2,13}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
                Thread.CurrentThread.Priority.ToString(),
                threadCount.ToString("N0"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might get more traction if posted as an issue to the dotnet/runtime repo on GitHub.

Comment: In my experience over 45 years, changing process or thread priorities makes very little difference except in a system that is already overloaded.

Comment: @user207421 agreed. Messing with thread priority is, in my experience, the kind of snake oil that gets applied when there's a fundamental underlying application issue that nobody is willing to address. The OS is almost always smarter and better at scheduling work than you the programmer... let it do its job.

Answer (score 1):

I was reluctant to post this as an issue on GitHub dotnet/runtime, as I was pretty sure the issue was with my ignorance of scheduling on Linux - and so it proved. However, I bit-the-bullet and [got an answer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60114). I needed to use `chrt` to run my process using the `SCHED_RR` scheduling policy. Thanks janvorli@github.